# code for mutate_at to recode values in a vector of column names

Tags: r, case, mutate

Im trying to write a code, that will take colnames out of a given vector, and in each of  these columns recode 1<-5,2<-4,3<-3,4<-2,5<-1
big5qflip is the vectore of columns that I need to recode out of a questionnaire,
I'm having trouble getting it to work, and writing case_when correctly

```
big5new%>%mutate_at(vars(big5qflip),case_when(
  big5qflip==1~5,
  big5qflip==2~4,
  big5qflip==3~3,
  big5qflip==4~2,
  big5qflip==5~2
))
```

thank you!

when I tried the code above I got the follwing error
Error in `mutate_at()`:
! `.funs` must be a one sided formula, a function, or a function name.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

`mutate_at` has been superseded by `across`, so here's a solution using this function. Also notice the `{{ ... }}` syntax to refer to the colnames in `big5qflip`:

```r
library(dplyr)

big5new <- data.frame(
  X = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2),
  Y = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  Z = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
)

big5qflip <- c("X", "Y")

newcodes <- 5:1
names(newcodes) <- 1:5

big5new %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      {{ big5qflip }},
      ~ do.call(recode, append(list(.x =.x), newcodes))
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option. You can use `factor` to set the levels in the reverse order and then `as.numeric` to get the level index which is the inverse of the number.

```r
library(tidyverse)

big5new <- data.frame(
  X = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2),
  Y = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  Z = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
)

big5qflip <- c("X", "Y")


big5new |>
  mutate(across(all_of(big5qflip), \(x) as.numeric(factor(x, levels = 5:1))))
#>   X Y Z
#> 1 5 2 1
#> 2 4 2 1
#> 3 5 2 1
#> 4 3 2 1
#> 5 4 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
The code I was writing ended up working after a few tweeks
here is the final code

``

```
big5new<-big5new%>%mutate_at(vars(big5qflip), ~case_when(
  .==1~5,
  .==2~4,
  .==3~3,
  .==4~2,
  .==5~1
))
```